# Bathroom vent fan electrical question

Tags: electrical, wiring

Wiring Diagram

[image]

My Diagram of how the wiring should be. Can someone confirm the diagram?
Also on the actual switch box, there is currently three pairs coming. I.e. with only one hot. Why would there be three wires when there was just a light and switch before? I got confused after removing the original equipment.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's difficult to give good answers when you ask multiple questions; you might want to split "why are there three incoming lines, only one hot" into a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The one hot is the supply to the switches and outlet your incoming hot should be a black wire that should be connected to 1 side of each switch and the outlet. The white neutrals are pigtailed together and feeding the humidistat, light and outlet. The grounds should be pigtailed and attached to the metal box. So 3 cables is correct: 1 for incoming power, 2 supplying the fan & light.